# Cannot use the special principal 'sa'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

When I try to run the command:

```
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'sa', @rolename = N'serveradmin'
GO
```

I get the error:

> Msg 15405, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_addsrvrolemember, Line 45
>   Cannot use the special principal 'sa'.

Ideas/suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

'sa' is a reserved login for the sysadmin; it's already a member of the sysadmin group, which trumps all other groups.  You don't need to add it to any roles, so why are you trying to do that?

Comment: I can give you a reason why I should modify `sa` => I need to run bulk insert which depends of bulkadmin ... which can't be added to sa...

Comment: members of the sysadmin role can perform any activity in the server.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659.aspx

Comment: Sorry to say this but isn't working for my 2012 SQL server version. It works just with windows logon, not with sysadmin(`sa`)... Maybe is just my case by this happens on 2 PC and 1 Server

Comment: That's probably because your server is configured to use Windows authentication only, not mixed mode.  Try this: SELECT CASE SERVERPROPERTY('IsIntegratedSecurityOnly')   
WHEN 1 THEN 'Windows Authentication'   
WHEN 0 THEN 'Windows and SQL Server Authentication'   
END as [Authentication Mode]

Comment: It's `Windows and SQL Server Authentication` according the result as I know already.