# Cannot use the special principal 'sa', error 15405

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to execute this query:

```
exec sp_addsrvrolemember 'sa', 'sysadmin'
```

unfortunately I get this error:

> Cannot use the special principal 'sa'

I searched the net for debug, my dbOwner is sa, authentication is Windows and SQL Server, user mapping is alright, and even I execute:

```
use mydatabase 
execute sp_changedbowner 'sa', 'true'
```

but still I get that error, any idea?!

Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188629/cannot-use-the-special-principal-sa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186320.aspx):

> The role membership of the sa login and public cannot be changed.

I believe the built-in `sa` account would already be sysadmin on the whole server/instance anyway, so you shouldn't need to do this.